# Master Master replication not working showing

Tags: mysql, replication

error from **master 1**

Last_SQL_Error:

> Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`stylanzo_live`.`report_viewed_product_index`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_REPORT_VIEWED_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON)'
>   on query. Default database: 'stylanzo_live'. Query: 'INSERT INTO
>   `report_viewed_product_index`
>   (`visitor_id`,`customer_id`,`product_id`,`store_id`,`added_at`) VALUES
>   (NULL, NULL, '1092', '23', '2015-05-28 19:20:00') ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE `visitor_id` = VALUES(`visitor_id`), `customer_id` =
>   VALUES(`customer_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `store_id`
>   = VALUES(`store_id`), `added_at` = VALUES(`added_at`)'   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:

error from **master 2**

> Last_SQL_Error:
>
> > Error 'Duplicate entry '157493' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default
> >     database: 'stylanzo_live'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `log_visitor`
> >     (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`,
> >     `store_id`) VALUES ('7059f889233675a315cd2a35a92e2480', '2015-05-28
> >     19:20:27', '2015-05-28 19:20:27', '0', '23')
>
> ```
> SELECT create_statement FROM common_schema.sql_foreign_keys WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='report_viewed_product_index';
> ```

Also, when I am starting replication it shows duplicate error again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to both Masters, then you have found two reasons not to write to both masters.  Instead, write only to one Master, and leave the other as a "hot standby".

Discuss the details of inserting into `log_visitor`, *maybe* we can help you unravel it.  There is a skip counter to get past something like a dup key and get replication going again; you may have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your support.

I have already skip the error cause from  my replication  by adding skip parameter in my.cnf file. reset  i am looking form a  db that can help to speepup my e commerce website. i guess mongodb would be the right option. we are currently using mysql as a DB.

Comment: As a good practise, do not skip the errors, identify the error and fix it on slave. The speed of your website depends on many factors such as quality of sql queries, hard disk type, amount of memory, computation capacity, etc.